# Replace JQuery Version on a Joomla Menu Item

Tags: jquery, joomla3.0

I want to have different jQuery versions on specific pages.

I tried to do it through a system plugin but the available events don't have any parameters so I can not change something in there.

Then I tried through the view.html.php of my corresponding page.
I tried JDocument::getBuffer() but the response was null.

I tried JDocumentHTML::getHeadData() but I get null on the script subset. 
I guess this is because it returns information only about scripts added through JHTML::script function and not the scripts added through template or system.

so any help is appreciated,

thanks Christoforos﻿